# Trying to Parse and Display Image Using Feedjira Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rss, feedjira

I'm trying to display an image using the Feedjira gem for an RSS reader that I'm working on.

I created the method in the model:

**Feed.rb**

```
def self.feed_image(url)
    Feedjira::Feed.add_common_feed_element 'img'
    image = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse url
end
```

I'm trying to display it in the show page so I call it in the controller:

**feeds_controller.rb**

```
 def show
    @feed = Feed.find(params[:id])
    @title = @feed.feed_title
    @entries = @feed.entries
    @feed_image = Feed.feed_image(params[:id]) <-----
 end
```

I added the params in order to pull the url that is calling the feed on the show page. I try to display it in the view as follows:

**show.html.erb**

```
<h3><%= @feed.url %></h3>
<%= image_tag @feed_image %>  <---------
<% @entries.each do |t| %>
  <%= link_to t.title, t.url %></br>
  <small><%= t.published %></small>
  <%= sanitize t.summary %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to call it:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `request_uri' for #<URI::Generic /1>):
  app/models/feed.rb:19:in `feed_image'
  app/controllers/feeds_controller.rb:12:in `show'
```

I'm not sure if it's not reading the URL correctly or where exactly I went wrong. Anyone have any idea where I went wrong.

Comment: What is the value of `url`?

Comment: This isn't valid Ruby: `image_tag @feed_image(url)`. Instance variables start with `@`; method names do not. I'm surprised this didn't raise a SyntaxError. Are you sure this is the actual code you're running? Did you mean to do `image_tag feed_image(@feed.url)`, perhaps?

Comment: URL is a mistake. I think I left it there because it was asking for an argument. Then I realized I needed to add the params.

Comment: Hey Jordan, I tried your suggestion and it still gives me a 'request_uri' error.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual code you're using. I'm not sure what you mean by "URL is a mistake." What is the value of the variable you're passing to the `feed_image` method?

Comment: Well, I was hoping by calling the params on that particular id, that would act as the variable since the feed itself is derived from a call to a URL.